# wordpress website transfer from one machine to another

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I installed wamp and wordpress locally. My friend also installed wamp and wordpress locally and started working on a website. I want him to send me what he finished so I can continue working on it. So he sent me his www folder inside wamp installation folder and I paste it inside my www folder. But when I open the website in browser it is empty (default one with Hello word). What should he send me, so I can continue working on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a wordpress website, it's not as easy as copy-paste; but it's not too difficult.

After they have given you all the physical files, your friend should

1) export their database (the name starts with `wp_`) using phpMyAdmin, and you should

2) import it with phpMyAdmin [note: if you want to overwrite your wordpress database, do this: 2a) as a backup, export your database with phpMyAdmin; and 2b) select all tables in your database and 'drop' them. Now the database is empty and you can import your friend's inside it.]

When this is done, you should

3) use phpMyAdmin to edit the first two entries in the table `wp_options`, inserting the proper path to your local website; then you should

4) assign to this database the username-password combination present in the `wp-config.php` file, in the main folder of wordpress. You do this with phpMyAdmin. Alternatively, you can edit `wp-config.php` so that it carries the proper password-username combination for your system.

**IF** **there is nothing of interest in your friend's database (as posts, pages, themes or plugins settings that you need etc) then you can *skip* steps 1,2 and 3.**

This should do it. :)

Comment: I got exported databes and imported it. Where can I find wp_options? I just see wp_options.ibd and wp_options.frm file in wamp/mysq/... The username and password are same in wp-config.php and database. When I go to localhos/mysite wordpress login appears, I type in username and password, but they are incorrect. I tried with my friend's username and password, but it didn't work too. Why?

Comment: Don't look for files. The tables are within phpMyAdmin. Go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ and look to the left at the list of databases on the left. Click on it and the list of tables will show.

Browse `wp_options`, and check these two values: `siteurl` and `home`: they should point to your localhost folder where wordpress is.

Comment: sorry, stupid question to you bambi, Why it says you preferred the other answer to my detailed instructions? (No offense Jonathan). :) (I'm new here, just trying to get how it works).

Answer (score 1):

The content of your WordPress installation is stored in a mySQL database, not on the file system. The files your friend sent you is WordPress itself and doesn't change anything contentwise.

Your friend needs to export (dump) his database to a SQL file. This can be done with a tool like PhpMyAdmin or mySQL Workbench. Take this file and import (overwrite) your local database with it. **Better make a backup of your database before!**